# Problems applying Boolean modifier to mesh using arrayed object to make Colander

Tags: modifiers, topology, artifacts

I'm trying to make a colander by taking a basic mesh I created using the screw and solidify modifier and cutting out the holes using a Boolean modifier with a cylinder that I have applied three array modifiers to (as you can see in the picture), but when I add the Boolean modifier the mesh just disappears. I've applied all the scales, the objects have a common origin, there are no non-manifold faces and the normals all seem fine, so I'm a bit confused what the issue is. If I add the Boolean modifier before the Solidify modifier I get a result, but it's inaccurate and with horrible artefacts (even with four levels of subdivision before the Boolean). Here's the .blend file, thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The result you have is correct but the subdivision surface modifier doesn't have the geometry to make it look nice.  You could try marking the edges of the holes as creases with SHIFT E.  Then the subdivision surface will know where the edges are.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so the only solution would be to apply the Boolean modifier first and then apply subsurf afterwards?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was the only solution but it is the only one I can think of.  Apply the boolean then mark the circle boundaries as edges and the the subdivision surface would be happier.  It might be easier to model one quarter of your model though and let the mirror or array modifier handle the rest.